# Why is my react native not opening a simulator?

Tags: linux, react-native

I'm using React Native and Linux to create a test app.

When I type `npm start` to the command line. I get the below message.

[image]

However no "simulator" or "server" pops up showing me the app.

When I click reload I get the warning message.`warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.`

Comment: hello try to run from xcode first react-native start then open xcode and open ios folder and do hit start icon it will work for android same with android studio

Comment: npx react-native run-android or npx react-native run-ios, with npm start you only start the react native bundler server

Comment: Since you are using it on Linux, you need to run your emulator from Android Studio before executing ```npm start``` command.

Answer (score 1):

npm start does not open simulator, you should open you simulator and run your project (with npm run android or npm run ios) then it will run in your simulator, you can also connect your phone to pc with usb cable and run your project and it will run in your phone. you can use Android Studio to open a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have already opened a virtual device and after running `npx react-native start` you get `No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed.` message, you need to add the ipaddress:PORT inside the debug menu of the app, you can open the menu by using `Ctrl + M`. The default port is 8081. After adding that simply hit R once or twice on your keyboard and now it should work as expected.

Comment: Where do you add port number? Also if Ctrl+M doesn't work, how else can someone open debug menu?